# Planar quadrangulations with only non-convex faces

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Do there exist planar quadrangulations that only consist of non-convex quadrilaterals? If so, do these types of quadrangulations have any special properties? I can only think of one example of this type of a quadrangulation, and it has only two faces and five vertices. When going past this, does a quadrangulation necessarily always have at least one convex face?

Answer (score 2):

Many (assuming you want edges to be straight). For an example of one that should show you some of the ways to build these up, see the picture.[image]

As soon as you have such a quadrangulation, you can add an extra vertex and face by just "copying" a vertex of an existing face and making it hug the contours of the old face.

EDIT: As per Misha's example, these graphs can have minimum degree 3.

Comment: A degree-$2$ vertex is not necessary. Here is an embedding of the cube graph with only concave faces: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbGhU.png

Comment: @MishaLavrov Aah, nice spot! I wrote the last sentence after failing to find such an embedding of the cube :P

Comment: Any quadrilateral, convex or not, can be used to tile the plane.